# Warning in install.packages : cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'

Tags: r, package, install.packages

I have attempted to download R package `memoise`:

```
 install.packages("memoise")
```

However, I have recevied the following error message:

> trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.0/memoise_0.1.zip'
>       Warning in install.packages :
>         cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
>       Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
>         cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.0/memoise_0.1.zip'
>       Warning in install.packages :
>         download of package ‘memoise’ failed`

I am connected to the internet and the WWW. In addition, I am connected to a work network. I am using the RStudio IDE.

Does anyone have any advice for how I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Try `update.packages()` first. Maybe this will solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as I can see there is no "memoise_0.1.zip" at http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.0/ . However, there is the "memoise_0.2.1.zip" file.

What version of RStudio IDE are you using? Do you have memoise already installed? Maybe you should try to update the memoise package.

Comment: Hi! I'm using the following version: RStudio 0.98.501, and I do not  have memoise installed (as far as I can tell).

Comment: What version do you get with:
 

`tmp <- available.packages(contriburl="http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.0/")`
&
`tmp[ grep("memoise", tmp[,1]), ]`

Comment: This was probably better posted as a question until you had more information to provide a full answer.

Answer (score 2):

I returned to this problem this morning. I restarted RStudio and tried the following again:

```
install.packages("memoise")
```

This time I received the following response:

```
Installing package into ‘\\oxdc/userdata/jolyon.faria/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.0/memoise_0.2.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 16813 bytes (16 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 16 Kb
```

This time it (unexpectedly) 'found' the correct webpage so problem solved. Thanks for your help.