# R package "proto" installation failing on ubuntu

Tags: r, rstudio, proto

I am trying to install the R package "proto" on a Ubuntu machine.

However, I am getting below errors...

```
Warning in install.packages :
  URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/proto_0.3-10.tar.gz': status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot download all files
Warning in install.packages : 
  download of package ‘proto’ failed
```

Comment: The file doesn't exist at the specified location - "404 Not Found" - try another CRAN mirror maybe.

Comment: You are trying to install an old version of the package. The current version is 1.0.0. If you needed the old version, you could get it from CRAN as well, but different URL (see "Old sources" on the proto package page).

Comment: I am not choosing the version. just running the install command without any extra options, like this...'install.packages("proto")'

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing more searching on StackOverFlow and this question seems to be similar but for a different package - 
[Warning in install.packages : cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264519/warning-in-install-packages-cannot-open-http-status-was-404-not-found?rq=1)

I restarted the RStudio and it worked and I am able to install package proto.

thanks